# Generating CCD document using MDHT API

Tags: java, hl7, ccd, mdht

I am trying to use MDHT API to generate CCD documents. I am doing this in the following way.

Downloaded Java runtime libraries and placed them in classpath and writing code to generate all the sections using MDHT API.

Writing code for each section is taking long (a bit complicated). I was wondering if I am missing anything. Is there any open source mdht GUI that  generates code for each section or am I moving in the right direction?

I am currently stuck at Medications Section/Immunization Section. Can anyone please redirect me to any examples/tutorials related to each section. I have already looked at user guide/developers guide.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @keerthi, What API did you end up using?

Comment: @PaulBellora The [Healthcare IT](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6433/healthcare-it) site didn't have enough activity during the beta, and has been closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think MDHT API will only provide a Model for the CCD document.
if it contains any default implimentaion to generate CCD document,,i dont know..
any way better you just generate the XML in DOM,STAXs API.

[CCD example link](http://repo.openehealth.org/confluence/display/ipf/CCD+Profile+Support#CCDProfileSupport-Payerssection)

Another better API that i found is MIRTH
follow the link

[Mirth User guide](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/MR/CDAPI+User+Guide)

Comment: I'm about to get started with [Open Health Tools MDHT](https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/sf/projects/mdht/) to generate CDAs. I'll report back with results if it succeeds. It turns out [MIRTH CDAPI costs $30,000/yr](http://www.mirthcorp.com/products/mirth-connect#Pricing) to use.

Comment: Open Health Tools MDHT is no doubt a time savior.

Comment: @Churro and Abin-m-devasia, links to MIRTH and "CCD examples" are dead.

Comment: @naXa it's been a long time since I worked on this, and I'm no longer in the health industry. Looks like openehealth URLs changed, and MIRTH password protected their wiki. Try one of these search results: [CCD example link](http://openehealth.org/dosearchsite.action?key=&queryString=ccd+profile+support).

Answer (score 3):

The best place to look for help/sample code is the developers forum:  [Eclipse Community Forums » Model Driven Health Tools](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=323).

You may need to create a (free) account to get access.

You could also go to the forums to post your specific MedicationsSection/immunization question for a possible specific answer.

Another good site is CDA tools: [MDHT Developers Guide](http://www.cdatools.com/docs/developeruserguide/org.openhealthtools.mdht.cda.doc.developerguide/topics/topic_Developers_Guide.html). Look at [Produce CDA Content using MDHT API](http://www.cdatools.com/docs/developeruserguide/org.openhealthtools.mdht.cda.doc.developerguide/tasks/t_Produce_Goal.html).

There are countless examples of building documents in the test code projects.
Download the [All In One (MDHT_CDATools)](https://github.com/mdht/mdht-models) from GitHub linked in the MDHT project site and look at the code in the test projects such as: [org.openhealthtools.mdht.cda.consol.example](https://github.com/mdht/mdht-models/tree/develop/examples/org.openhealthtools.mdht.cda.consol.example)

The closest (current) thing to a GUI based document building application in MDHT would be using the all in one to modify the existing models and generate sample snippets/documents that way (or creating a model from scratch, which includes only what you need). If you wanted the entire document produced in XML, you could then generate the instance from GeneralHeaderConstraints as opposed to any of the many child templates (which would give you snippets). Either way, this is not really the intention of the model interface (it's more for conformance) and would take you far longer to implement than using the API itself - which accesses the models which already exist in order to auto-generate conformant content quickly.